# Write column by column using Apache POI

Tags: java, insert, apache-poi, multiple-columns

How to write column by column using Apache POI?

I have a custom map in which I have keys containing multiple values.

```
{a=[1, 2], b=[3, 4, 5]}
```

Now I want to write these things into excel having a and b as column name and their values as cell value.

```
Desired Output
a      b
1      3
2      4
       5
```

All I am getting is writing row by row using Apache POI. Can anyone suggest me trick so that I can write it column by column?

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: ok @AndrewThompson, I will keep that in mind from next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer, actually POI only supports row by row insertion , so to do column by column insertion  I applied this logic

```
   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet");
    //Create a new row in current sheet
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    //Create a new cell in current row
    for(String key:map.keySet())
    {
        Cell cell1=row.createCell(columnNum);
        cell1.setCellValue(key);
        //System.out.println(map.get(key));
        List<Integer> columnValues = map.get(key);
        int tempHeight=columnValues.size();
        /*if(maxRows<tempHeight)
        {
            maxRows=tempHeight;
        }*/
        int temp=1;
        for(int i:columnValues)
        {
            Row row2;
            //System.out.println("no of rows:"+(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1)+", height:"+tempHeight);
            if(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()-1>temp-1)
            {
                //System.out.println("take row");
                row2=sheet.getRow(temp);

            }
            else
            {

                //System.out.println("Row inserted");
                row2=sheet.createRow(temp);
            }
            Cell cell2=row2.createCell(columnNum);
            cell2.setCellValue(i);
            temp=temp+1;
        }

        columnNum=columnNum+1;


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that POI only supports adding rows. You can create number of rows by looking longest value list. In your case **b**. Then traverse cells and insert values.
[POI Sheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow%28int%29)

Comment: I am also going by the same logic, look for particular keyset and find its depth and then compare it to maxRows we have inserted in excel, but I am not able to make it efficient, anyways ur suggestion is highly appreciated