# How to write column by column data in Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, fileoutputstream, xssf

I want to write column by column to an Excel file but I don't know how to do this. Is it possible to make it? I looked in the docs and see no methods to write column by column.
Here is my code:

```
private void writeColumnByColumn() throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // here i want to write "a" in the first column, "b" in the second and "c" in the third
    }
    
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("ok.xlsx");
    try (outputStream) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563539/write-column-by-column-using-apache-poi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write column by column using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563539/write-column-by-column-using-apache-poi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work.

```
  private void writeColumnByColumn() throws IOException {
   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
          cell.setCellValue(strings[i]);
   } 
 
   FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("ok.xlsx");
   try (outputStream) {
       workbook.write(outputStream);
   }
  }
```